# ajax code not working

Tags: php, ajax

this is my js code

```
function load(div_tag,thefile)
{

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById(div_tag).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and this my php code

```
echo '<div style="float:left; margin-left:2px; margin-top:17px; background:#666; text-align:center; width:auto;"><a href="#div" onclick="load(\'div\',\'include/comment_form.php\')" style="text-decoration:none;"><b style="color:white;">Add comment</b></a></div>';

echo '<div id="div" align="left" style="clear:both;"></div>';
```

the problem is it's working in xampp but it is not working in my website. I am a starter please help me.

Comment: Any error messages on the console?

Comment: Where does it *not* work?  For instance the `<a` tag `onclick` depends upon the return value of *load* - which doesn't return anything and thus is browser dependent (make it return *true* to activate the redirect).

Comment: how and where are you calling `load` function?

Comment: No solving the problem, but why do you use echo for HTLM content ? This forces you to use backslashes oO

Comment: Thanks friend it works 100% when i return true. thanks.

Comment: Added a more formal answer, since the above comment was actually the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to fit the successful comment:

The function `load()` should return a value *true* or *false*, since it is in the `onclick` handler of a `<a` tag. Since `load()` does not return anything, the result is browser dependent.

Just return *true* in `load()` to activate the anchor redirect

```
function load(div_tag,thefile)
{
    ...
    xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    return true;
}
```